# « Sous les ors de [+ place] », est-elle une expression idiomatique ou non ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

> [**Sous les ors**](http://www.lemonde.fr/election-presidentielle-2017/article/2017/04/24/les-britanniques-incredules-devant-le-succes-du-pro-europeen-macron_5116344_4854003.html) de la résidence de l’ambassade de France à
>   Londres, de discrets applaudissements ont accueilli, dimanche 23 avril
>   à 20 heures, l’annonce des résultats du premier tour de la
>   présidentielle française, diffusés sur deux écrans plantés devant les
>   tapisseries des Gobelins de la salle de bal.

Après avoir lu cette phrase beaucoup de fois, je crois que je sais ce que **sous les ors de [+ place]** signifie ; cette expression parle du centre du pouvoir étatiste d'une nation. Au moins, celle-ci est ma déduction en la lisant.

Mais je voudrais savoir si ma déduction est correcte ; *et surtout pourquoi cette expression (est-elle une expression idiomatique ?) n'existe pas dans les dictionnaires en ligne dans lesquelles je l'ai trouvée*.

Et finalement, si cette expression existe dans aucun dictionnaire en format classique, je voudrais que vous m'en indiquiez la source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

« ors » est tout simplement le pluriel de « or » (le métal).

*Sous les ors de ...* est une expression qui désigne les lieus où on peut trouver des plafonds dorés ainsi que toute sorte d'objet dorés (encadrements de tableaux, statues ...).

Comme indiqué par Laure, on trouve également une expression signifiant la même chose : « sous les dorures. »

Cependant, selon [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sous%20les%20dorures%2Csous%20les%20ors&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csous%20les%20dorures%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csous%20les%20ors%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsous%20les%20ors%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSous%20les%20ors%3B%2Cc0) « Sous les ors » est plus fréquemment utilisé que « sous les dorures. »

Comment: Donc si elle est une expression, pourquoi n'existe-elle pas dans les dictionnaires ? Celle-ci est ma questionne, comme tu peux lire au-dessus de ton réponse.

Comment: Bien sûr, c'est ça. Ce n'est pas "une expression"; c'est une rédaction; "sous les pavés, la plage"! Un slogan. Par exemple. Cherchez sur Utube: François Béranger: Sous les pavé. C'est toute une éducation....

Comment: Aussi plus généralement au TLFi pour [or](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/or), les _ors d'un tableau/Décoration dorée ou peinture contenant une certaine proportion d'or_.